# Applying the command unique and lower on a variable

Tags: matlab

I currently having a script in matlab that creates a cell array that holds all the terms in a document. I need to use the command unique and lower on the variable to avoid duplicates. I can't work out how to place this on the variable.

```
Mylist = [];

for C = 1:length(docs)
   list = tokenize(docs{C}, ' .,-');
   Mylist = [Mylist; list];
end
```

Comment: Why not `unique(lower(docs))` ?

Comment: Where exactly what i put that?

Comment: wouldn't i add it on the variable list?

Answer (score 0):

I create a new variable and used unique and lower on the current cell array.

```
 Newlist =  unique(lower(list));
```

My final code is

```
Mylist = [];

for C = 1:length(docs)
   list = tokenize(docs{C}, ' .,()"%-+/');
   Newlist =  unique(lower(list)); 
   Mylist = [Mylist; Newlist];
end
```